# Doctrine use operators in select fields

Tags: php, sql, select, doctrine, operators

I try to convert this SQL query to *QueryBuilder* code :

```sql
SELECT invoice.id, COALESCE(invoice.remainingAmount, 0) = 0 AS fullyPaid
FROM invoice
```

I got that :

```php
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('invoice')
           ->select(
               'invoice.id',
               'COALESCE(invoice.remainingAmount, 0) = 0 AS fullyPaid'
           )
;

return $qb
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
    ;
```

But, when I executed this code, I got the error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 36: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '='

I tried by adding the condition between brackets `()` and with operators `<>` and `!=`, without success.

Does someone know how to fix that, or have a workaround to avoid to treat the condition on PHP side?

Answer (score -1):

Try tu use the `case`. For example:

`(CASE WHEN COALESCE(invoice.remainingAmount, 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fullyPaid`